# Facing trouble in Configuring Tor to hash a new password in windows 10

Tags: tor, hashing, web-crawler

I have tried and read various articles over the internet about hashing a new password for Tor.
My tor is installed in local disk D
I used the following commands in the command prompt

```
D:\softwares\tor\Tor Browser\Browser>firefox --hash-password <my password> | more
D:\softwares\tor\Tor Browser\Browser>firefox --hash-password <my password> > tor-password.txt
```

to get the output of the hashed password but there is no o/p of the hashed password instead the command is prompting to open the Tor browser. And the text file in the location is also empty.
I noticed that my tor application name was firefox.exe in the installed location but it created a shortcut named tor on the desktop.
After getting my hashed password I am intending to use it in torrc ( TOR configuration file) to
Update the “ControlPort” listener for TOR to listen on port 9051, as this is the port to which TOR                        will listen for any communication from applications talking to the Tor controller,
Update the hashed password and to
Implement cookie authentication

I am following the below articles to build a web scraper.
[How to scrape websites without getting blocked](https://www.scrapehero.com/how-to-prevent-getting-blacklisted-while-scraping/)  and
[How To Make Anonymous Requests using TorRequests and Python](https://www.scrapehero.com/make-anonymous-requests-using-tor-python/)

Please mention if I can provide any further details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, here is a complete guide on how to setup tor (not Tor Browser), by following this guide you don't have to use Tor Browser, instead you can configure all browsers to use tor network.

First, download the latest tor browser from by clicking this official link:https://dist.torproject.org/torbrowser/10.0.7/torbrowser-install-win64-10.0.7_en-US.exe, then install it; The default install location on desktop is good enough, because you can easily open its folder and traverse it. Download tor Windows Expert Bundle by clicking this official link:https://www.torproject.org/dist/torbrowser/10.0.7/tor-win32-0.4.4.6.zip, unzip it to a location with a path that is easy to remember(i.e. D:).

Second, get familiar with the folder structure of ***Tor Browser*** and ***tor*** (notice the case difference):

Tor Browser:

[image]

tor:

[image]

Third: copy the Pluggable transports folder in *\Tor Browser\Browser\TorBrowser\Tor\ to *\tor-win32-0.4.4.6\Tor (in this example the asterisk means %userprofile%\desktop):

```
copy "%userprofile%\desktop\Tor Browser\Browser\TorBrowser\Tor\PluggableTransports" %userprofile%\desktop\tor-win32-0.4.4.6\Tor\
```

Fourth, learn how to correctly configure torrc file, below is a correct torrc file, you just have to replace the pathes(%userprofile%\desktop will not work):

```
Bridge obfs4 172.86.144.104:443 3F437A9AB9D086322F4FAD1B658EFEF9B2B8B64E cert=6MYDi1ir/HjySknjeaG+hs07FZfYUhlOpAYdxifK80ISMISe+9EJp4t5dq4XIrRh4G1jKg iat-mode=0
Bridge obfs4 155.133.131.55:51429 9247336B1E19BD22C71A9C678B120F7A816D65AB cert=VBYOXYf+SbRu2dCHJkLuL9y7YX4IWhucHGg3ES+l/KKxe3KL+zhCHr5hRqgSE6w80bZvCA iat-mode=0
ClientTransportPlugin meek_lite,obfs2,obfs3,obfs4,scramblesuit exec %userprofile%\desktop\tor-win32-0.4.4.6\Tor\obfs4proxy.exe
ClientTransportPlugin snowflake exec %userprofile%\desktop\tor-win32-0.4.4.6\Tor\snowflake-client.exe -url https://snowflake-broker.azureedge.net/ -front ajax.aspnetcdn.com -ice stun:stun.l.google.com:19302,stun:stun.voip.blackberry.com:3478,stun:stun.altar.com.pl:3478,stun:stun.antisip.com:3478,stun:stun.bluesip.net:3478,stun:stun.dus.net:3478,stun:stun.epygi.com:3478,stun:stun.sonetel.com:3478,stun:stun.sonetel.net:3478,stun:stun.stunprotocol.org:3478,stun:stun.uls.co.za:3478,stun:stun.voipgate.com:3478,stun:stun.voys.nl:3478
CookieAuthentication 1
ClientOnionAuthDir %userprofile%\desktop\tor-win32-0.4.4.6\Data\Tor\onion-auth
DataDirectory %userprofile%\desktop\tor-win32-0.4.4.6\Data\Tor
GeoIPFile %userprofile%\desktop\tor-win32-0.4.4.6\Data\Tor\geoip
GeoIPv6File %userprofile%\desktop\tor-win32-0.4.4.6\Data\Tor\geoip6
UseBridges 1
HTTPTunnelPort 127.0.0.1:8080
SOCKSPort 127.0.0.1:9150
ControlPort 127.0.0.1:9051
HashedControlPassword 16:F043C6FEBA7365B9608B00A7B780BCFA453F3A637A8E9F0C9B0C2098CE
```

The first two lines are bridges, you can get bridges here:https://bridges.torproject.org/options

You should run this command to create onion-auth directory:

```
md %userprofile%\desktop\tor-win32-0.4.4.6\Data\Tor\onion-auth
```

replace path %userprofile%\desktop with actual path

And generate certificates before using tor:

```
%userprofile%\desktop\tor-win32-0.4.4.6\tor\tor-gencert.exe --create-identity-key
```

It will ask you to enter PEM pass phrase, input anything you want, make sure you inputed the same thing twice, there will be no prompt, after you had completed input press Enter;

Now run tor-gencert.exe again, this time without arguments:

```
%userprofile%\desktop\tor-win32-0.4.4.6\tor\tor-gencert.exe
```

Replace path and enter PEM passphrase you had entered earlier.

Fifth you can install tor as a service with this(replace path):

```
%userprofile%\desktop\tor-win32-0.4.4.6\Tor\tor.exe tor --serviceinstall -options -f %userprofile%\desktop\tor-win32-0.4.4.6\Data\Tor\torrc
```

Then you can start tor by this:

```
net start tor
```

To stop tor:

```
net stop tor
```

Use these codes to config all browsers to use tor as proxy:

```
netsh winhttp set proxy 127.0.0.1:8080
reg add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" /v ProxyServer /t REG_SZ /d "127.0.0.1:8080" /f
```

Then all your browsers will automatically use tor (there will be no network if tor isn't running and/or connected), to revert it:

```
netsh winhttp reset proxy
reg delete "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" /v ProxyServer
```

Sixth, to hash passwords:

```
%userprofile%\Desktop\tor-win32-0.4.4.6\Tor\tor.exe --hash-password PASSWORD
```

Replace path %userprofile%\Desktop\ with where you actually put tor folder, and replace the PASSWORD with the actual password you want to use; copy the hash (like 16:C7EF87D04112053160FCC1517B8AF112C1BFD523BE1B1B415619CE4A9B) and replace the hash found in the above torrc example with that hash.

To use the hash, while tor is running, run:

```
telnet localhost 9051
```

Then paste these:

```
AUTHENTICATE PASSWORD
```

Replace the PASSWORD with the actual PASSWORD, there might be no text displayed, just press Enter, if it says 250 OK then you are done.

Finally, the geoip database that comes with tor is outdated, you can update it by converting an up to date GeoLite2-Country.mmdb file. (This is optional, but it's better to do this.)

Go to this website:https://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geoip2/geolite2/, click "SIGN UP FOR GEOLITE2", and complete the signup procedure; Once signed up, log in your account, scroll down to find "GeoIP2 / GeoLite2", click download files:
[image]

Scroll down to find "GeoLite2 Country"

[image]

Then click "Download GZIP" to download it; once downloaded, decompress it using any software that can decompress .gz files. Remember path to GeoLite2-Country.mmdb or drag it to desktop (%userprofile%\desktop).

Go to this site:https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nmathewson/mmdb-convert/master/mmdb-convert.py, copy the file by CTRL+A then CTRL+C, use Notepad++ to create a new file, then CTRL+V to paste the file, navigate to line 444 by CTRL+F then type "time" without quotes and press Enter two times, replace:

`time.strftime('%B %d %Y', time.gmtime(build_epoch)))`

with:

`time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d', time.gmtime(build_epoch)))`

then save it as mmdb-convert.py, preferably on desktop (%userprofile%\desktop), download and install Python: If your computer is 64-Bit, click this:https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.9.1/python-3.9.1-amd64.exe, else this https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.9.1/python-3.9.1.exe, make sure to click "Add Python to environment variables" checkbox.

Finally cd to where you put the files(in my case it's desktop), run these:

```
cd %userprofile%\desktop
python mmdb-convert.py GeoLite2-Country.mmdb
```

And copy the resultant geoip and geoip6 files to *\tor-win32-0.4.4.6\Data\Tor (the asterisk means where you put tor to), and replace the files found there.

***UPDATE*** Terribly sorry if the above guide doesn't work, I made a mistake, so tor service can't be started, now they should be fixed

Comment: thanks, It's a great read. I really appreciate it, man 